# How to add numbers given as a list of tuples given in the form: ('name', number)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sum, tuples

def highest_n_scores(scores, n = 5):

Each player plays the game some number of times, each time resulting in a tuple (name, score) for how much that player scored in the game. Given all games played as a list of such tuples, add up the n highest scores for each individual player as the total score for that player. Create and return a list that contains tuples (name, total) for the players and their total scores, sorted in ascending order by name. If some player has played fewer than n times, just add up the scores of whatever games that player has played.

The code is below but I wanted to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this and it also doesn't seem to work using the tester.

```
def highest_n_scores(scores, n):

    bill = sorted([p for (t,p) in scores if t == 'bill'])
    jack = sorted([p for (t,p) in scores if t == 'jack'])
    sheldon = sorted([p for (t,p) in scores if t == 'sheldon'])
    tina = sorted([p for (t,p) in scores if t == 'tina'])
    amy = sorted([p for (t,p) in scores if t == 'amy'])
    bob = sorted([p for (t,p) in scores if t == 'bob'])

    scoreBill = sum(bill[-n:])
    scoreJack = sum(jack[-n:])
    scoreSheldon = sum(sheldon[-n:])
    scoreTina = sum(tina[-n:])
    scoreAmy = sum(amy[-n:])
    scoreBob = sum(bob[-n:])

    return sorted([('bill', scoreBill), ('jack', scoreJack), ('sheldon', scoreSheldon), ('tina', scoreTina), ('amy', scoreAmy), ('bob', scoreBob)])
```

I get the correct result, but the tester for all values however, the tester I was given to test the code says my answer is wrong.

list :

```
[('bill', 10), ('jack', 6), ('sheldon', 3), ('tina', 2), ('amy', 3), ('sheldon', 6), ('tina', 7), ('jack', 2), ('bob', 3), ('bob', 4), ('bill', 3), ('bill', 9), ('sheldon', 5), ('amy', 2), ('jack', 7), ('sheldon', 5), ('sheldon', 7), ('bill', 1), ('bill', 9), ('sheldon', 5), ('bill', 2), ('bill', 6), ('jack', 6), ('bob', 4), ('tina', 5), ('sheldon', 4), ('sheldon', 2), ('amy', 6), ('bob', 7), ('jack', 2), ('bob', 5), ('sheldon', 9), ('jack', 5), ('amy', 9), ('bob', 7), ('tina', 6), ('tina', 2), ('amy', 7), ('jack', 10), ('tina', 4), ('bob', 5), ('jack', 10), ('bob', 7), ('jack', 5), ('amy', 4), ('amy', 8), ('bob', 4), ('bill', 8), ('bob', 6), ('tina', 6), ('amy', 9), ('bill', 4), ('jack', 2), ('amy', 2), ('amy', 4), ('sheldon', 1), ('tina', 3), ('bill', 9), ('tina', 4), ('tina', 9)] when n = 3
```

list return :

```
[('amy', 26), ('bill', 28), ('bob', 21), ('jack', 27), ('sheldon', 22), ('tina', 22)]
```

Comment: Why not use a dictionary instead that contains a list of scores from one person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently are creating as many variables as the names, which is not very efficient and scalable, instead you could think on using a dictionary to store your information

You can start by collecting all scores in a dictionary, with the key as the name and the value as the list of scores. You then iterate over the dictionary, and for each name, you sort the score in descending order, and find the sum of the first n elements.

The code will look like:

```
scores = [('bill', 10), ('jack', 6), ('sheldon', 3), ('tina', 2), ('amy', 3), ('sheldon', 6), ('tina', 7), ('jack', 2), ('bob', 3), ('bob', 4), ('bill', 3), ('bill', 9), ('sheldon', 5), ('amy', 2), ('jack', 7), ('sheldon', 5), ('sheldon', 7), ('bill', 1), ('bill', 9), ('sheldon', 5), ('bill', 2), ('bill', 6), ('jack', 6), ('bob', 4), ('tina', 5), ('sheldon', 4), ('sheldon', 2), ('amy', 6), ('bob', 7), ('jack', 2), ('bob', 5), ('sheldon', 9), ('jack', 5), ('amy', 9), ('bob', 7), ('tina', 6), ('tina', 2), ('amy', 7), ('jack', 10), ('tina', 4), ('bob', 5), ('jack', 10), ('bob', 7), ('jack', 5), ('amy', 4), ('amy', 8), ('bob', 4), ('bill', 8), ('bob', 6), ('tina', 6), ('amy', 9), ('bill', 4), ('jack', 2), ('amy', 2), ('amy', 4), ('sheldon', 1), ('tina', 3), ('bill', 9), ('tina', 4), ('tina', 9)]

def highest_n_scores(scores, n = 5):

    scores_dict = {}

    #Make a dictionary of name to list of scores
    for name, score in scores:
        #Set the default value of the dict as an empty list
        scores_dict.setdefault(name, [])
        #Append the score to the name
        scores_dict[name].append(score)

    result_list = []

    #Iterate over the dictionary
    for name, score in scores_dict.items():

        #For total score, sort the list in descending order, and take the sum of first n elements
        total_score = sum(sorted(score, reverse=True)[:n])
        result_list.append((name, total_score))

    return result_list

print(highest_n_scores(scores, 3))
```

and the output will be

```
[('bill', 28), ('jack', 27), ('sheldon', 22), ('tina', 22), ('amy', 26), ('bob', 21)]
```

Comment: why do you need to import defaultdict and how is it being used? sorry it might be a dumb question, but I'm new.

Answer (score 0):

using a dict you could do this.

```
def highest_n_scores(scores, n):
    result = dict()
    for name , score in scores:
        if name in result.keys():
            result[name].append(score)
        else:
            result[name] = []
            result[name].append(score)

    for key , item in result.items():
        result[key] = sum(result[key][-n:])

    return sorted(result.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1] , reverse=True)
```